# Removing temporary internet files from Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, temporary-files, temporary-internet-files

Hello Superuser community,

I have to work with Windows 10 and am in dire need of some disk space. Thus, I'm trying to use the cleanup tool to free some space. Unfortunately, I'm not able to delete the "temporary internet data" of my admin account. Its size is currently more than 6 GB which would help me quite a lot.

This is what I tried so far:

1. Using the cleanup tool as normal user and admin user
2. Using [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner)
3. Starting in safe mode and trying to remove the data from there
4. Following the steps mentioned [here](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-temporary-files-wont-delete/)

Any further hints or ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: `Cleanup Tool` can sometimes report the incorrect size.  Have you confirmed that space is actually being consumed?  It's easy enough to go to the directory, that is configured to store the temporary internet data, and delete the files contained within it manually.

Comment: You can try `Foldersize` by `Rotebeta`. This software will scan whole drive and will show easy to understand list of folders with size. I found it very useful in situation you mentioned and made few GB of space in just few minutes.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks for pointing me to that but all I achieved with this batch file was to crash my PC. Luckily, I managed to restart it safely.

Comment: @Ramhound: You're right. This folder doesn't even seem to exist... Strange...

Answer (score 0):

As far as deleting any "locked" files go, clean method is described here: https://www.wikihow.com/Delete-a-Locked-File (both procexp and Safe mode options are viable and pretty clean). If you don't mind getting your hands dirty, I had good results with software Unlocker (http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). Unlocker can actually do a lot of damage when used unproperly, but deleting temp files of whatever should be ok, simply make sure software whose temp files you are about to delete is not running and also make sure that they don't containg anything you could need (browsing history, etc.)

When it comes to freeing up space in general on Windows machines, I usually hardcore deleted all I could from `C:\<user>\AppData\Local` and `C:\<user>\AppData\Roaming`. This icludes TEMP directories (you can delete all it allows you to, needed or in-use files are protected) and usually big space monger were leftover files from uninstalled software. So just go through mentioned directories by hand and if you see directory named after software that is no longer installed and you don't want to save its configuration, just delete it and empty Trash Bin after.

Also, delete Cache of your browser (it should allow you to do it from its Settings), online games and clear your Download folder (since it is usually full of unneeded things and is not cleaned by Windows Cleanup tool).

Lastly, delete all movies you already saw, they usually take majority of disk space :)

P.S.: Empty Trash Bin after all of theese as trashed items still can take disk space.

Comment: I'm not so sure whether that's the right approach here. Those folders contain plenty of useful files.

Comment: Of course they do, rule of thumb is, as I said, *delete only folders of software you know you uninstalled*.

Comment: But how exactly would that help to remove temporary internet files?

Comment: Right, back to original question, please see updated answer.